# Laravel class confusion

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function inside one of my Controller classes:

```
public function postToken(){
        $bridgedRequest  = OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request::createFromRequest(Request::instance());
        $bridgedResponse = new OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Response();

        $bridgedResponse = App::make('oauth2')->handleTokenRequest($bridgedRequest, $bridgedResponse);

        return $bridgedResponse;
}
```

It's being called fine, but I'm getting a whole pile of "Class not found" errors...

e.g.:

`<span class="exception_message">Class &#039;OAuth2&#039; not found</span>`
`<span class="exception_message">Class &#039;App\Http\Controllers\Request&#039; not found</span>`
`<span class="exception_message">Class &#039;App\Http\Controllers\OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request&#039; not found</span>`

How do I import these classes correctly? I have them in my composer.json file and I already performed `composer update`...

Here's my composer.json file:

`"require": {
                "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
                "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "^1.7",
                "bshaffer/oauth2-server-httpfoundation-bridge": "^1.1"
        }`

I'm new to Laravel so I'm still getting used to how things work...

I think this is just a simple `use` import statement, but I'm afraid I'm very stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP namespaces you occasionally have to use *absolute* namespaces in order to the class loader to work properly.

Replace `OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request` with `\OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request` and see how it goes.

You can also import classes, interfaces and so on with the `use` statement.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request as OAuth2Request;

class YourController { ... }
```

Now the `Request` from the `OAuth2` vendor is available inside `YourController` directly by using `OAuth2Request`.

Regarding `Request::instance()`, you need to somehow get the request object for use in the method `postToken`. You can use *method injection* as you are working inside a Controller:

```
public function postToken(\Namespace\To\Request $request)
{
    $request->instance();
}
```

Comment: I simply can't get it to work... This line fails: `$bridgedRequest  = OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge\Request::createFromRequest(Request::instance());` I included these namespaces: `use OAuth2;` and `use OAuth2\HttpFoundationBridge;`

Comment: Did you remember to inject the other `Request` class instance? You could also try `\Request::instance()`.